# Find running processes created by Mac Automator

Tags: mac, automator

Is there any way to view automator process that are running?

About a year ago I created a workflow or something similar in Mac's Automator. When I took screenshots mac would place them on the desktop. I created a small script to take move those screenshots to a different folder. I want to change what folder those are saved in now. Problem is, I can't figure out how to edit my workflow. The biggest problem, I don't know where the workflow/file is stored. The process is always running so anytime I take a screenshot it is moved. Is there any way to view automator process that are running?

Also, I know there are other ways to make screenshots appear in different folders. I still want to find this process/script and kill it =)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal window and try using the following command:

```
ps aux
```

It should give you a list of all running processes.

To get a process tree of the running processes, use:

```
ps axjf
```

Comment: ok, any idea what kind of process I am looking for?

Comment: @zechdc You might try something like `ps aux > /path/to/empty/textfile.txt` to output the results of `ps` to a file for better searching. I would look at any filepath in the running processes and see if it gets you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your folder actions?

```
"/Users/zechdc/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts"
```

If you have ruled out folder actions I would check any programs such as Hazel to make sure they are not performing the action. After that I would check launch agents with `launchctl list` in Terminal.

Comment: see my edited version.

Comment: Ok, I ran the `launchctl list`. Not really sure what I am looking for at this point.

Answer (score 0):

you can find/edit your workflows from: ~/Library/Workflows/

Comment: As written, your answer provides very little useful information. Can you expand it on a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and was solved by running 
`ps aux` and killed this process
`60035   ??  S    192:23.86 /System/Library/CoreServices/ScriptMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/ScriptMonitor`
with `kill 60035`.

Answer (score -1):

There is a check box when you click the options tab inside every comand that says show when the script is running, (or something like that) check this box and you will see when that comand is working.